# TypeError: 'Connection' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python

Hi I'm following a tutorial online to build a flask web app and keeping coming across this error when I try to store information into my db via the sign up button.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL(app)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'pass'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'table'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)




@app.route("/")
def main():
return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
return render_template('signup.html')

@app.route('/signUp', methods = ['POST','GET' ])
def signUp():


_phonenumber = request.form['phonenumber']
_name = request.form['name']
_password = request.form['password']

if _phonenumber and _name and _password:
    conn = mysql.connect()           
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
    cursor.callproc('sp_createphoneuser',   (_phonenumber,_name,_hashed_password))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(data) is 0:
        conn.commit()
        return json.dumps({'message':"User created successfully !"})
    else:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})

 else:
    return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'}) 



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True    
    app.run(port=5002)
```

So that is the code I have and everytime I try to register a user I get this error in terminal:

```
File "/home/john/FlaskApp/app.py", line 35, in signUp
conn = mysql.connect()
TypeError: 'Connection' object is not callable
```

My theory is that there was a problem during installation but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please check that the indentation in your code is correct.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem recently and I solved it

by using 
**`conn = mysql.connect`** instead of **`conn = mysql.connect()`**

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you get a connection, or a cursor, with flask.ext.mysqldb. See [the documentation](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

It should be:

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

so you don't need to explicitly create a connection at all.

(Note that there does seem to be a separate project, flask-mysql, with a slightly different API - that could be where the confusion is coming from.)

Comment: Thanks for the help but now I'm getting this error:  _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1046, 'No database selected')